# Agglomerating with the other deontic operators

Tags: logic, moral-dilemma

Agglomeration in deontic logic is when you have **OB***A* and **OB***B*, so you have **OB**(*A*&*B*). Agglomeration is controverted for reasons of theorizing about moral dilemmas. I'm looking through the SEP article on deontic logic, but I haven't yet found discussion about whether **PM***A* and **PM***B* goes to **PM**(*A*&*B*), or then if **FR***A* and **FR***B* goes to **FR**(*A*&*B*).

"Intuitively," there are moral situations that have been described as incompatible things being separately permitted, e.g. you are permitted to go to either of two restaurants on opposite ends of town, but on account of their distance from each other, it is not possible to go to both restaurants at the same time. "Ought" is often taken to imply "can" and "may" can be thought to imply "can," at least some of the time, but then here **PM**(go to restaurant 1, go to restaurant 2) should mean that it is possible to go to both restaurants at once. Perhaps this goes to show that something like going to a restaurant is too unimportant to even be substantially permitted; but again, "intuitively," it seems to point away from **PM**-agglomeration.

As for **FR**-agglomeration... Well, again, couldn't incompatible things be forbidden, but because their (the things/their being done) conjunction is impossible, then if "ought not" implies "contingently," we would say that it was contingent that their conjunction not be done? But we assumed that their conjunction was impossible because of their characteristic incompatibility. So one might think that **FR**-agglomeration doesn't go through.

From the normal modulations of deontic operators into the forms of the others (e.g. **OB** into **~PM~**), would it follow that if the permission and prohibition operators are not subject to agglomeration, neither would be **OB**? And then we would have a reason aside from dilemma theory, for denying agglomeration.

(P.S. Or consider **SR**, for "it is supererogatory that." One way to approach supererogation is to have a sequence of increasingly supererogatory options; but so **SR**(*n*) and then **SR**(*n*+1) are given such that if one has only gone so far as *n*, one perforce has not yet gone so far as *n*+1, and qualified by "only" as such, the doing of only *n* is incompatible with the doing of only *n*+1. So perhaps there is a case where **SR**-agglomeration falls apart, too.)

Comment: Wouldn't duality relate agglomeration of conjunctions for OB to agglomeration of *disjunctions* for PM, not of conjunctions? Also, under duality, Chisholm's paradox goes through even without agglomeration, see [Cariani, p.12](https://philpapers.org/archive/CARDLA-7.pdf). So what we have is a reason for rejecting duality itself and keeping obligations and permissions as separate primitives. We also have independent reasons for that, the thing was aped from modal logic mostly as a technical convenience.

Comment: On how agglomeration for obligations interacts with permissions under duality see [Governatori-Rotolo, Is Free Choice Permission Admissible in Classical Deontic Logic?](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3641195)

Comment: I suggest not conflating 'agglomeration' with 'conjunction'. Agglomeration is a non-technical term: we are asking how we should combine A with B when we have OB(A) with OB(B). Conjunction is one possible answer, but it may fail, e.g. if it is physically impossible to do both and ought implies can. Maybe there are weaker forms of agglomeration than conjunction. The same issue arises with substructural logics, where we might wish to combine sentences in more subtle ways than by using classical conjunction.

Comment: @Conifold I guess in my own system, I start with something like the AK reduction, so none of the operators are primitive directly; regardless, there are two kinds of permission operator that I end up, and I've never actually worked out whether/how they reconstruct the conversion of **OB** to **~PM~**. I start with an imperative, go to an imperative question, "Why do *a*?" and then have, "There is some *J* such that it is why do *a*." **OB** goes with (but is not the same as) the base case where *a* doesn't have negation, conjunction, or disjunction affecting its expression.

Comment: Then "differential permission" is for an imperative, "Do *a* or do not do *a*," in that the imperative is actively present, but internally neutral between outcomes. Then "indifferential permission" is for ~(Do *a*) & ~(Don't do *a*), i.e. there is no imperative in place either way, in the first place. Differential **PM** thematically resonates with the "formula" for **SR** being, "Do A or do (A&B) or do (A&B&C) or ..." (where A = the "least that can be done").